# HttpClient wont work in jelly bean?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I've build app android uses http client to get content from URL,

```
         String getRequest(String SUrl){
             String vResult = "TEST";
        //SUrl result of "http://mydomain.com/file.php?var=21"
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request;            
            try{                
                request=new HttpGet(SUrl);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


                vResult=request(response);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("From Server", ex.getMessage());

            }
            return vResult;
        }

        public static String request(HttpResponse response){
            String result = "";
            try{
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result = str.toString();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                result = "Error";
            }
            return result;
        }
```

in android gingerbread the code above work fine get content from server,but in jelly bean the code result log like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

why i get null in jelly bean even i already declare all variable?

thanks

Comment: Your app will fail regardless of Android version if `ex.getMessage()` returns null at `Log.e("From Server", ex.getMessage());` with above NPE.

Comment: Change it to this: Log.e("From Server", ex.getMessage()+"");

Comment: @ltvie I believe you try to request network in UI thread and got `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, which is prohibited from HONEYCOMB (api level 11).

Comment: thanks for quick response. and my problem is solve.. i want ask again,why getMessage() causes my app error in Jelly bean?

Comment: Keep in mind `getMessage()` isn't a root cause exception. Sometime, `exception.getMessage()` return `null`. But your problem is request network on main thread which caused a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` (without message) as I guessed.

Comment: Ehmm.. I get it..
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
       catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("From Server", ""+ex.printStackTrace());

        }
```